# AWS S3 Access is denied in IE11

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, internet-explorer-11

I am new to AWS - i am using ng-file-upload-shim.min.js for upload image but getting error in IE11 - Access is denied.

In CORS - my configuration

```
<CORSRule>
          <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
          <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
          <AllowedMethod>DELETE</AllowedMethod>
          <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
          <AllowedHeader>*</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
```

and in js

```
 for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                          var fileKey = fileNameTypeJsonArr[i].filename;

                          // Add the promises to the promise list.
                          promises.push(Upload.upload({
                              url: $scope.endpointUrl + $scope.bucketName,
                              method: 'POST',
                              fields: {
                                key: fileKey,
                                AWSAccessKeyId: $scope.key,
                                policy: result[i].policy,
                                signature: result[i].signature,
                                acl: $scope.acl,
                                "Content-Type": fileNameTypeJsonArr[i].type,
                                "x-amz-server-side-encryption": "xxxx",
                                filename: fileKey
                              },
                              file: files[i]
                          }).progress(function (evt) {
```

it is working fine in all brower  but getting error in IE11

Comment: Did you take a look at IE 11 console? Maybe it's throwing some JS error...

Comment: In console i am getting: Error: Access is denied.